# How to render a React component with survey.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

Here is a working survey.js with react example: http://plnkr.co/edit/qXdeQa6x2FHRg0YrOlPL?p=preview

My html also does have in head the `<script src="https://unpkg.com/survey-react"></script>` included.

In my main.jsx I'm calling the rendering of a div that will be filled up based on a json file and by multiple react components, in my json array I have a questions json object too for survey.js. What I would like to achieve is to render a survey when the questions object is being reached in parsing the array.

In my top level component I have this calling for it:

```
  if (section.hasOwnProperty('questions')){
            return <Questions key={i+"questions"} id={i+"questions"} questions={section.questions} />;
```

The Questions.jsx:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Survey = require('survey-react');
var Questions = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      Survey.Survey.cssType = "bootstrap";
      Survey.defaultBootstrapCss.navigationButton = "btn btn-green";
      window[this.props.id] = new Survey.Model( this.props.questions );
      var questionid = this.props.id;
        var idi = this.props.id.replace("questions","");
        return (
            <dt>
          <div id={this.props.id}></div>
          </div>
     </dt>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = Questions;
ReactDOM.render(<Survey.Survey model={window[questionid]} />, document.getElementById({questionid}));
```

It does compile without errors but then in the browser I get the console errors:

> TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_react** is undefined[Learn
>   More]
>   ReferenceError: questionid is not defined

Seems like I try to do it the wrong way, but how to do it right? I'm new to react and not familiar with using reactDOM inside of a component and is my first project on survey.js as well.

Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import * as Survey from 'survey-react';
import 'survey-react/survey.css';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {    
    Survey.Survey.cssType = "bootstrap";
    Survey.defaultBootstrapCss.navigationButton = "btn btn-green";
  }

  render() {    
    var json = { title: "Product Feedback Survey Example", showProgressBar: "top", pages: [
        {questions: [
            { type: "matrix", name: "Quality", title: "Please indicate if you agree or disagree with the following statements",
                columns: [{ value: 1, text: "Strongly Disagree" },
                    { value: 2, text: "Disagree" },
                    { value: 3, text: "Neutral" },
                    { value: 4, text: "Agree" },
                    { value: 5, text: "Strongly Agree" }],
                rows: [{ value: "affordable", text: "Product is affordable" },
                    { value: "does what it claims", text: "Product does what it claims" },
                    { value: "better then others", text: "Product is better than other products on the market" },
                    { value: "easy to use", text: "Product is easy to use" }]},
            { type: "rating", name: "satisfaction", title: "How satisfied are you with the Product?",
                mininumRateDescription: "Not Satisfied", maximumRateDescription: "Completely satisfied" },
            { type: "rating", name: "recommend friends", visibleIf: "{satisfaction} > 3",
                title: "How likely are you to recommend the Product to a friend or co-worker?",
                mininumRateDescription: "Will not recommend", maximumRateDescription: "I will recommend" },
            { type: "comment", name: "suggestions", title:"What would make you more satisfied with the Product?", }
        ]},
        {questions: [
            { type: "radiogroup", name: "price to competitors",
                title: "Compared to our competitors, do you feel the Product is",
                choices: ["Less expensive", "Priced about the same", "More expensive", "Not sure"]},
            { type: "radiogroup", name: "price", title: "Do you feel our current price is merited by our product?",
                choices: ["correct|Yes, the price is about right",
                    "low|No, the price is too low for your product",
                    "high|No, the price is too high for your product"]},
            { type: "multipletext", name: "pricelimit", title: "What is the... ",
                items: [{ name: "mostamount", title: "Most amount you would every pay for a product like ours" },
                    { name: "leastamount", title: "The least amount you would feel comfortable paying" }]}
        ]},
        { questions: [
            { type: "text", name: "email",
                title: "Thank you for taking our survey. Your survey is almost complete, please enter your email address in the box below if you wish to participate in our drawing, then press the 'Submit' button."}
        ]}
    ]};

    var model = new Survey.Model(json);    
    return (
      <Survey.Survey model={model}/>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and here a live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/surveyjs-react-stackoverflow45544026

Comment: In the end I stopped doing this integration. This example seems to be ok so I will accept it, but to be safe, for future visitors it would be better to post your code here as well.